# Run a formula multiple times in same sitting

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to make a spreadsheet to keep track of the values of each upgrade in the game [Reactor Idle](http://www.kongregate.com/games/Baldurans/reactor-idle). Each "level" increases the value by a certain percent. To predict the value after the next upgrade I created the formula `=X+((X*Y)/100)` where `X` is the current value and Y is the percent increase. i.e. if the Coal Burner is `A1` then the formula `=A1+((A1*25)/100)` entered into the "B" column.

Problem is that there's no way to increase the value multiple times without just recreating the formula in separate cells or copy and pasting the values from one cell to another. The former ends up taking up too much space on the chart for my liking and the latter becomes time-consuming since the upgrades don't carry over to each new cell.

What I'd like to do is just recreate the Upgrade chart with It's values (maybe in/referenced by a separate sheet?) and as I increase the level number the resulting value is increased the same number of times. For example, the Coal Burner starts with a value of 380. If I increase it's level to 10, the result should be 3539.025784.

Is there a way to do this? I'm still relatively new to the more complex formulas and applications in spreadsheet so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The formula `=A1+((A1*25)/100)` can be written as `=A1*1.25`

Multiplying a number by 1.25 several times means multiplying it by a *power* of 1.25.

For example, `=A1*1.25^10` returns 3539.025784, as you want.

In general, your formula could be like `=A1*1.25^B1` where A1 has the original value and B1 has the number of upgrades.